# Laravel multiple belongsTo users

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to show Races + people that attend the races, I'm using table relationships but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

view:

```
@foreach($leagues->races as $race)
        <!-- ATTENDANCE track -->
        <div class="col s12 m6">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="{{ asset("img/tracks/.png") }}">
              <span class="card-title red attendance-track-box"><b>{{$race->event}}</b></span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content attendance-content">
                <ul>
                  @foreach($race->attendances as $attendance)
                    @if($attendance->status == 1)
                      <li class="border-left-green">{{$attendance->user->username}}</li>
                    @elseif($attendance->status == 2)
                      <li class="border-left-red"></li>
                    @elseif($attendance->status == 3)
                      <li class="border-left-cyan"></li>
                    @endif
                  @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-action">
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn green">Yes</a> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn red">No</a> <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Maybe</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
```

model Leagues:

```
class Leagues extends Model
{
    //
    public function teams(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\teams');
    }
    public function races(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\races');
    }
}
```

model Races:

```
class Races extends Model
{
    //
    public function attendances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\attendances');
    }
}
```

model Drivers: (use this one for drivers listing)

```
class Drivers extends Model
{
    //
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'users_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

model Attendance:

```
class attendances extends Model
{
    //
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'users_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

model Users

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    //
}
```

I've posted the Drivers model since I also call upon belongsTo.
basically, I've copied the code and it works for drivers yet it doesn't for attendance

Error I get:

> Trying to get property 'username' of non-object

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'psn', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model relationships are only doing the inverse `belongsTo`. Your model relationships need to go both ways if you want to use `belongsTo`, but your relationships are only going in the inverse. Define the relationship using   `hasMany`, `hasOne`, or the like first, then you can define the inverse in the other model.

Example Drivers:

```
class Drivers extends Model
{
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'users_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Example Attendances:

```
class attendances extends Model
{
     public function user(){
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Users', 'users_id', 'id');
     }
}
```

Example Users:

```
class Users extends Model
{
     public function attendances()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\attendances');
     }

     public function drivers()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Drivers');
     }
}
```

Each class needs to reference each other. One with the `hasMany`, `hasOne`, or the like to define the relationship and the other needs the `belongsTo` to define the inverse of the relationship.

Comment: The classes don't need to reference each other. What you're referring to is called the inverse of a relationship. The `attendances()` relationship on the `Users` model is only required if you need to access a given users attendances but its not required if you want to access a given attendance's user. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: Yes but they are just doing the inverse "belongs to" portion, that won't work. They need to define the relationship using hasMany, hasOne, or the like first, and then optionally use the inverse. You can't do the other way around.